# How can make a dynamic data in Django template?

Tags: ajax, django

example views:

```
dinamic=0
while dinamic<10:
    dinamic=dinamic+1
```

how can I render on my template 1 then 2 then 3 ... makes the page reload

Comment: What do you mean makes the page reload? can you explain more exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template is rendered at server level so you can achieve at client side. You need to go with Jquery or any other Javascript framework.

If you have data you can iterate in template using [{% for %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for) loop.